# How to get SpannableString from Edittext

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add an Image at certain cursor position to edit text every time I click the button
but when I try to add second image , the first image disappear

```
  void addImageToEditText(){
    int postiton =  mainEditText.getSelectionStart();
    mainEditText.getText().insert(postiton,String.valueOf(' '));
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(mainEditText.getText().toString()+"  ");
    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.unknown);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, postiton, postiton+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mainEditText.setText(ss);
}
```

I tried the html one, but it is not working

Comment: better create a new Span every time . keep the click count value as global and add span With the help of a loop .

Comment: when you call `mainEditText.getText().toString()` you are losing previously set `ImageSpan` (as spans belong to `SpannableString`, not just usual `String`). as above suggested: it would be better to keep `SpannableString` somewhere (in class?) instead of creating new one every time. or if creation is needed you have to set ALL spans again, all previously set + new one

Comment: I created a new SpannableString with image and insert to the mainEditText at the position. It kinda work now.